# Cannot run Curried Function in REPL

Tags: scala, currying

I am trying to run below curried function in 
https://scastie.scala-lang.org.

But instead of showing the output 'sumInts : 14' it shows some lambda reference hash string.

```
  def sum(f:Int => Int) : (Int, Int) => Int = {
     def sumF(a:Int, b:Int): Int = {
           if(a > b) 0 else f(a) + sumF(a+1, b)
     }
     sumF
  }

  def sumInts (a:Int, b:Int) = sum(x => x)

  sumInts(2, 5)
```

Comment: `sum(x => x)` returns a lambda. `sumInts` takes two parameters that it never uses and then returns the same lambda that `sum(x => x)` returns.

Comment: But sum function is supposed to take only one argument that is another function. Which in tern should apply to the integer arguments provided by parent function. Isn't it?

Comment: @KaizarLaxmidhar "But sum function is supposed to take only one argument that is another function." Ok. "Which in turn should apply to the integer arguments provided by parent function." No, argument function and returned function are two different functions. You do not apply returned function since you do not use `a`, `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant

```
def sumInts (a:Int, b:Int) = sum(x => x)(a, b)
```